# How to return Date from a DatePickerDialog to Mainactivity

Tags: java, android

I have managed to make a date picker class but now I want the value from the date picker dialog to be returned to the main activity class. Below is the code for the date picker dialog.

```
 public class DateChooser extends DialogFragment implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener{

    public int y,m,d;

    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        return new DatePickerDialog(getContext(),this,year,month,day);

    }
    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Toast!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        setDay(dayOfMonth);
        setMonth(month);
        setYear(year);


    }
```

I have called this class from the mainactivity.

```
public void dateSelect(View view)
{
DateChooser dateC = new DateChooser();
dateC.show(getSupportFragmentManager(),"tag");
}
```

Comment: Call method from activity or make interface.

Comment: A bit more elaborate please. :)

Answer (score 1):

Do this:

Add this to DateChooser Class:

```
private DateSelectedListener mListener;

@Override
public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
    // Do something with the date chosen by the user
    mListener.onDateSelected(view, year, month, day);
}

public void display(FragmentManager manager, String tag, DateSelectedListener listener) {
    super.show(manager, tag);
    mListener = listener;
}

public interface DateSelectedListener {
    void onDateSelected(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day);
}
```

in your Activity do this:

```
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements DateChooser.DateSelectedListener {
    //onCreate or whatever other method:
    dateChooser.display(
            getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(),
            "datePicker", this);
}
```

Good luck!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can create an interface e.g. like this

```
public interface DateListener {
    void onDateSelected(int day, int month, int year);
}
```

and implement it in your activity

```
public class YourActivity extends Activity implements DateListener {...}
```

then you have to implement the method in your activity...

In your `Fragment` add the following field:

```
private DateListener dateListener;
```

and add this code to your Fragment's `onAttach`:

```
 @Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);

    if (!(getActivity() instanceof DateListener)) {
        throw new ClassCastException("The activity inflating this fragment must implement DateListener!");
    }
    dateListener = (DateListener) getActivity();
}
```

Now you have set your activity as DateListener and can use it in the result of the `DatePicker`

Comment: onAttach is not a method of Activity

Comment: true, but you need it in the fragment anyway - it is called when the fragment is attached to the activity. And here you need to set your activity as DateListener

Answer (score 0):

```
 DatePicker datePicker = (DatePicker) findViewById(R.id.datePicker1);
 int day = datePicker.getDayOfMonth();
 int month = datePicker.getMonth() + 1;
 int year = datePicker.getYear();
String dateInString=year+"-"+month+"-"+day;
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
Date date = formatter.parse(dateInString);
System.out.println(date);
```